# Excel index Formula for finding row header value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Refer the attached image, I have table and the column header value in `C10` and data in `C11`, data value shall be near match should be not less than, with this I want to find the row header value (ie, `A,B,C,D,E`)

I could not get required result with the below index match formula -

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(C11,INDEX(B2:H6,match(C10,B1:H1,0),),-1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C13</kbd>

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,1/(INDEX(B2:H6,,MATCH(C10,B1:H1,0))>=C11),0))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cells <kbd>C13</kbd> & <kbd>D13</kbd>

```
=LET(α,ABS(FILTER(B2:H6,B1:H1=C10)-C11),FILTER(A2:A6,MIN(α)=α))
```

---

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6, 
  MATCH(MIN(ABS(INDEX(B2:H6,,
  MATCH(C10,B1:H1,1))-C11)), ABS(INDEX(B2:H6,,
  MATCH(C10,B1:H1,1))-C11), 0))
```

---

Comment: THIS worked for me, thank you

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, i am having new constrain, I want the second result for suggestion (examble ignore Row A in your image). is that possible without macro ?